# C# RestSharp ignoring timeout parameter?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a C# function that checks to see whether or not a proxy is valid by trying to connect to the REST API at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. However, the `RestClient` seems to be ignoring the 5000ms timeout value I gave it, and instead using a (default?) timeout of 2100ms.

Here's my function:

```
    private bool checkProxy(ProxyHolder ph)
    {
        bool success = false;
        String errorMsg = "";
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(ph.ip, ph.port);

        try
        {
            sw.Start();
            IRestResponse response = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new System.Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"),
                Timeout = 5000,
                ReadWriteTimeout = 5000,
                Proxy = wp
            }.Execute(new RestRequest
            {
                Resource = "todos/1",
                Method = Method.GET,
                Timeout = 5000,
                ReadWriteTimeout = 5000,
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            });
            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                throw response.ErrorException;
            }
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Success:" + success.ToString() + "|Connection Time:" + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "|ErrorMsg" + errorMsg);
        }
        return success;
    }
```

And here's the output from an invalid proxy:

> Success:False|**Connection Time:21.0209113**|ErrorMsgThe operation has
>   timed out

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This seems odd. I just tested this out locally with your code (excluding the `WebProxy` portion) and mocking a timeout by using [slowwly](http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/#go). I'm getting the following output: `Success:False|Connection Time:5.5118055|ErrorMsgThe operation has timed out.`. That at least seems to narrow the issue down to the `WebProxy` itself, or something else causing a delay between the end of the HTTP request and the finally block

Comment: @devNull you know what else is odd? I tried running it with `mono` on Ubuntu and it times out after `5.99` seconds.... however it also fails to connect to good proxies with `SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)`...