# HTTPWebRequest is not timing out

Tags: c#, .net

So I have the problem that any GET or POST Request, whether it is made with HttpWebRequest or RestSharp, does not time out after a certain amount of time when using a bad proxy for the request. I want the request to time out after a certain amount of time and there should be in both cases a default timeout of 100 seconds, as the default timeout of RestSharp requests are the default timeout of HttpWebRequests. But that's where things get weird. My request doesn't time out after 100 seconds and neither after setting it explicit to 5 seconds. It just waits for the response and blocks the whole program.
To conclude: the request waits infinitely for a response.

I did some research here on StackOverflow and other sites and it seems like nobody had that issue before. I also couldnt solve it with the solutions given to similar problems. A similar problem without a given solution can you find here [C# RestSharp ignoring timeout parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296820/c-sharp-restsharp-ignoring-timeout-parameter)
The difference is the user above has still a default timeout that is working fine (which is weird as it is 21 seconds).
Another user didn't had the problem using the same code, which is also weird but could lead to a solution

```
System.Net.CookieContainer cookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.de/?hl=de");

req.Timeout = 5000;
req.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
req.ContinueTimeout = 5000; //

string proxy = ""; //non working proxy here
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Split(':')[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy.Split(':')[1]));
req.Method = "GET";
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0";
req.Referer = "";

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();              
Console.WriteLine(resp.Content);
```

As I mentioned it should time out after 5 seconds, and without setting the timeout explicit after 100 seconds, but neither of that is happening. 
Edit: I have to add that the Timeout works fine without a non working proxy when set to a low amont like 5 milliseconds. It then throws a System.Net.WebException.

Comment: Can you use `async`? If so, using the `HttpClient` class with the `Timeout` property should work just fine

Comment: Wrong UserAgent with WebRequest. With that UserAgent, Google will activate the [HSTS](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiKopzDufPhAhXG0KQKHTs6D_4QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHTTP_Strict_Transport_Security&usg=AOvVaw1fchZaueG6yXEG2yoTKmy1) protocol: WebRequest knows nothing about HSTS and the server will wait for *interaction*. It won't timeout soon (but it will, the server will get bored). Use the IE11 header instead. The way you're trying to set the Proxy is weird.

Comment: Btw, you also need to set a [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I will try that, eventhough that wouldnt explain why it ignores the Timeout. When I set the Timeout to for example 5 milliseconds and run the same code without a non working proxy (!) it throws a System.Net.WebException that the Timeout is reached. I will add that to my original post.